# biblatex: How to remove space between von and Last?

Tags: biblatex

Certain prefixes (aka “von” parts, aka particles) end with an apostrophe or a hyphen (“d’Ormesson”, “al-Hakim”). These prefixes must not be treated as parts of the last name to allow formats like “d’Ormesson”, “al-Hakim” in the text, but “Ormesson, Jean d’”, “Hakim, Tawfik al-” in the references list.

Since biblatex does not parse `d’` in `d’Ormesson` as a prefix, the name has to be entered with a space between von and Last, as `d’ Ormesson`. (I'd consider this a bug, but that’s not my current concern.)

Now biblatex splits names into their elements, and when rendering adds spaces between the elements (using the `\bibnamedelim` macros). It *does not* add a space after a dumb apostrophe (that’s what I consider to be the correct, expected behaviour), but it *does* add a space after a smart apostrophe or a hyphen (that’s the incorrect bit).

The solution recommended by [TTB](http://tug.ctan.org/info/bibtex/tamethebeast/ttb_en.pdf) for bibtex, entering `author = "d’\relax Ormesson, Jean",` does not work for biblatex.

So my question is: How can biblatex be fixed to treat smart apostrophes and hyphens like dumb apostrophes here?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{orm-d,
  author = {d' Ormesson-Dumb, Jean},
  title = {Title: dumb apostrophe},
  date = {2015},
}
@book{orm-s,
  author = {d’ Ormesson-Smart, Jean},
  title = {Title: smart apostrophe},
  date = {2015},
}
@book{hak,
  author = {al- Hakim, Tawfik},
  title = {Title},
  date = {2015},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{\toggletrue{blx@useprefix}}
\AtBeginBibliography{\togglefalse{blx@useprefix}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section*{Text}
\cite{hak, orm-d, orm-s}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Output:

> **Text**
>   al- Hakim 2015; d’Ormesson-Dumb 2015; d’ Ormesson-Smart 2015
>   **References**
>   Hakim, Tawfik al- (2015). *Title.*
>   Ormesson-Dumb, Jean d’ (2015). *Title: dumb apostrophe.*
>   Ormesson-Smart, Jean d’ (2015). *Title: smart apostrophe.*

Expected:

> **Text**
>   al-Hakim 2015; d’Ormesson-Dumb 2015; d’Ormesson-Smart 2015
>   **References**
>   Hakim, Tawfik al- (2015). *Title.*
>   Ormesson-Dumb, Jean d’ (2015). *Title: dumb apostrophe.*
>   Ormesson-Smart, Jean d’ (2015). *Title: smart apostrophe.*

Note: Using xelatex/fontspec/Times since pdflatex/default font did not display the smart apostrophe at all. Mac OS X 10.10.5, TeX Live 2015.

Comment: The proper output in French is d’Ormesson, Jean: the "particule" shouldn' t be separed this way.

Comment: Possibly, but that’s not the point. (“d’Ormesson” just happens to be TTB’s example.)  – The point is that “d’” and “al-” should be parsed as prefixes/particles and properly joined with the last names, i.e., without space – something that already works for dumb apostrophes but not for smart apostrophes and hyphens.

Comment: Do you get different outputs for the two apostrophe characters in terms of character representation?

Comment: After experiencing [#87 at the Biber bugtracker](https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/87), I really think that your way of inputting names is not something Biber swallows easily. The underlying problem is really [#340](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/340), you need to find a way to properly tell Biber which part is to be seen as name prefix. Current parsing rules do not seem to cover your case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Edit*

Starting with version 3.2 of `biblatex` the name handling has been made a bit more flexible. You can now specify the characters after which the space before the family name should be swallowed with `\DeclarePrefChars`.

You probably want at least

```
\DeclarePrefChars{'’}
```

The default is `\DeclarePrefChars{'}` only (that coincides with the behaviour of earlier versions).

See also §4.7.5 *Configuring Punctuation and Capitalization*, p. 216 of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf).

---

*This part of the answer is kept for historical purposes only.*

The `name:` macros have some special code to deal with such name prefixes. The command you will be interested in is called `\ifpunctmark{<char>}`, it checks if the last character just printed coincides with `<char>`.

The default commands have

```
\ifpunctmark{'}{}{\bibnamedelimc}
```

We can then pretend all the other relevant characters are apostrophes as well with

```
\sfcode`\-=\blx@sf@apo
\sfcode`\’=\blx@sf@apo
```

which we can add into the `\blx@namecodes` macro where character codes for name processing are set up

```
\makeatletter
\def\blx@namecodes{%
  \ifnum\sfcode`\A=\@m
  \else
    \blx@setazcodes
  \fi
  \sfcode`\'=\blx@sf@apo
  \sfcode`\-=\blx@sf@apo
  \sfcode`\’=\blx@sf@apo
}
\makeatother
```

If you want to use this with (pdf)LaTeX you need to comment out the line with the unicode character `’` (`` \sfcode`\’=\blx@sf@apo ``).

In full (with Linux Libertine as font, because I don't have Times installed on my system)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[babel,german=guillemets]{csquotes} 
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{orm-d,
  author = {d' Ormesson-Dumb, Jean},
  title = {Title: dumb apostrophe},
  date = {2015},
}
@book{orm-s,
  author = {d’ Ormesson-Smart, Jean},
  title = {Title: smart apostrophe},
  date = {2015},
}
@book{hak,
  author = {al- Hakim, Tawfik},
  title = {Title},
  date = {2015},
}
@book{von,
  author = {von Scharnhorst, Johann},
  title = {Title},
  date = {2015},
}
@book{de,
  author = {de Haan, Joop},
  title = {Title},
  date = {2015},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\def\blx@namecodes{%
  \ifnum\sfcode`\A=\@m
  \else
    \blx@setazcodes
  \fi
  \sfcode`\'=\blx@sf@apo
  \sfcode`\-=\blx@sf@apo
  \sfcode`\’=\blx@sf@apo
}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{\toggletrue{blx@useprefix}}
\AtBeginBibliography{\togglefalse{blx@useprefix}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine}

\begin{document}
\cite{hak, orm-d, orm-s, von, de, vangennep, geer, worman, sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: example output]

Comment: Ok, but something’s weird: Add one

    @book{foo,
      author = {de Foo, Joe},
      title = {Title},
      date = {2015},
    }

and he’s rendered as “deFoo 2015“ in-text (no space).

Comment: @user22851 Ah, so it does. Try the edited version, it has to go a bit deeper into the innards of `biblatex`, but works now.

Comment: @moewe - can you propose a more general solution with a user-configurable interface to check a list of punctuation? I would gladly include this in the next release if so.

Comment: @PLK Not sure, the idea can surely be generalised. I'm just not sure about any adverse effects this might have. One would probably just have to look at `\blx@namecodes` where we already set `\sfcode`\'=\blx@sf@apo` and could of course can add other `\sfcode`\-=\blx@sf@apo \sfcode`\’=\blx@sf@apo` as well.

Comment: @PLK I'm not great with list processing, but one could just give the user a new option analogous to `\DeclareRangeChars` and then loop over the list assigning every character the new space factor.

Comment: @PLK Maybe I can cook something usable up later.

Comment: I incorporated @moewe's new code and so you can try biblatex 3.2 from sourceforge (needs biber 2.3 from there too). Just put `\DeclarePrefChars{'’}` in your preamble.